# Copy EC2 instance between regions

Tags: amazon-ec2

On the amazon ec2 Singapore region I have a single windows machine with an elastic IP.
I want to close this machine to the San-Paulo region so I will have two independent machines with the same contents. Each machine will be accessed by different people and will not share the same data.

I have created an AMI from the Singapore machine and transferred this AMI to the San-Paulo region. when I try to create an instance out of this AMI on the San-Paulo, the wizard asks for a VPC configuration. I did not know what to answer so I looked on my Singapore configuration and saw there is noting on the VPC settings in Singapore (I have no VPC). How can i create the same on San-Paulo?
In my attempts, I have created a new elastic IP on the San-Paulo region and deleted all VPC settings but that did not help. I am unable to create the machine as I have to select a VPC on step 3 of the new instance wizard.

A step by step instructions would help if possible as I am not too familiar with EC2

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the VPC question?
It is a default behavior now to actually have a VPC (and it doesn't matter if you have one or not) - so possibly AWS is enforcing a VPC now.
You can just add a public VPC and there is nothing different than not having a VPC for you...

Comment: @Osterjour, I selected the m1.medium machine and then I am prompted with this screen http://screencast.com/t/WGTtHDbjw

Comment: Yeah like I thought: AWS is enforcing the use of a VPC now. Just create one with the VPC wizard (use the option "VPC with a Single Public Subnet") and start the instance within this VPC and subnet. This shouldn't change anything for you and your instance compared to Singapore.

Comment: I asked amazon to restore my default VPC and after that installed the new machine. So far so good. Thanks @Osterjour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Osterjour suggestion, I asked Amazon to restore my default VPC and then created the instance from the AMI